# Create database to access small project inside wordpress from cyber panel

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, cyber-panel

I had setup wordpress project in main url : [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) with help of cyber panel in aws-ec2 free hosting.

I had domain and setup wordpress via cyber panel.

Now, I want to setup small php project inside this like: [www.example.com/mysmallproject](http://www.example.com/mysmallproject)

I had create folder : mysmallproject and add all files. its working well. I can access php file via browser.

**ISSUE** : I had created database via cyberpanel and assign domain. [image: database create]

It has username and password.

**NOW,** I need to access database. it requires username, password and database name and server name.

I have username, password, database name. But i dont know "**SERVERNAME**". I tried to get servername from my wordpress configuration file but its not working. Any suggestion will be appriciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The server name is your EC2 IP address or you can use "localhost".

Comment: i tried but its failed.